# Would it introduce lag and bad user experience to host a website with two hosting companies?

Tags: web-hosting, website-design, performance, user-friendly

I'm developing a website for a customer that has two companies, but the two are closely related. The customer wants two separate sites that look and function as one site as far as users are concerned. The reason for this is the customer intends to see half of the company in a year or so and to make the transition easier wants two sites, separate logins, etc.

Would the user experience a lag time when clicking back and forth on pages hosted on different accounts or pages hosted on different host companies? For example: Godaddy hosts half the pages/links and Hostgator hosts the other half of pages/links.

I understand that selling half of the company shouldn't dictate how the website is constructed, but this is how my customer prefers the setup. I'll be using Wordpress.

Comment: @Marilyn What specific user-experience metrics (like performance, conversion rate, etc.,) you are concerned more?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this, and the level of complexity required varies a bit:

### Option 1 - Serve on multiple subdomains

If the client is happy to have two subdomains for the two different parts of the company, you could have something like:

`www.example.com`
Serves pages for the primary company, potentially along with the "standard" about, contact, etc. type pages.

`othersite.example.com`
Serves pages for the secondary company, most of the navigation takes you back to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but other interlinked pages are still held on othersite.example.com

This should be fairly easy to set up, but does expose the fact that there are two separate areas at work - however this may be sensible if you're requiring separate logins for the users/visitors.

As others have mentioned you may also want to add redirects on both sites to ensure that if people attempt to access a page that should be hosted on the other site they end up on the correct site.

This also allows both sites to easily have versions of the same page (for example if you want separate contact or login forms on both sections).

You can configure subdomains to point to different IP addresses, so these can be separate hosting providers or just different plans with the same provider.

### Option 2 - Use a load balancer to split traffic

This is could be a much more complex option, but allows your client to serve both parts of the site with a single domain (i.e. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) but then internally route the requests to multiple servers.

The simplest way to then set this up would be for the secondary site to live under a directory on the main site (i.e. [www.example.com/othersite](http://www.example.com/othersite)), that way you can keep them separated, and have dedicated pages if you need them, but easily share pages if required. You would also be able to easily separate the media and other assets used by the pages.

You would then have a single published domain, but under the hood you would have two sites serving the application, and again these can be hosted with different providers as required.

### Considerations with both options

Depending on traffic levels and the hosting plans you've chosen visitors may experience a slight lag when moving between sites if the sites need to be "warmed up" to start serving traffic.

You'll also need to duplicate a reasonable amount of templates, image assets, etc. between the two sites, and keep these updated if any of the site furniture, navigation items, etc. change. Links between the two sites will need to be fully qualified, however the DNS lookup required for the domains shouldn't really be noticable when moving between the two sites.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because your IP address is fixed to one server and whenever you type the URL of your site browser going to specific **IP address that it assign to you by your hosting provider** I don't think that 1 site can accept to to IP addresses from different server also this is not possible on single server for one hosting provider you can redirect both to different IP address.

**Probable solution** for your problem is you can redirect a specific page of your current domain to another domain by using your server and c panel and **setting redirection rules.**

so whenever somebody click on that URL of your main website they give redirect to another website which you are hosting on somewhere on different server.

Doing this you can use your different server and main website smoothie and also get a space for your web app on other hosting but the mask domain remains the same like you just redirecting it and.

And sure that your redirect enjoyment don't get index you can keep your old website domain dating topic without using that to directly the another domain that you are hosting on another server

so what I am trying to say is **disallowed search engine to index your second site** just index your primary main site

Comment: Thank you for responding! I like your redirect option. I didn't say that the customer has two domains that will be used for the two  websites. I'm going to try hosting on two different accounts and hosting companies.

Answer (score 0):

Your question assumes third party hosting, but have you considered hosting yourself?

If you manage/host the servers yourself and have a high throughput connection between the two servers, you might consider virtual directories.  A virtual directory is a web directory that is mapped from another file location.  Different vendors have different implementations but both MS Windows and Apache support this.

Your website might look something like example.com and example.com/remotesite where remotesite is your virtual directory.  The remotesite directory can reside anywhere the hosting web server example.com has physical access to.  That might be a directory that is hosted locally, but updated manually via  VPN, or a high throughput VPN connecting the webserver to the remote site.

When the remotesite company is sold, host the remotesite directory under it's own domain name, and redirect all of the exameple.com/remotesite to the newsite(dot)com.

To be sure, this is not without problems.  The new site is likely to have a dip in SEO until search engines catch the redirects and adjust.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I didn't think about hosting myself because I'm not that experienced at hosting. I didn't say that the customer has two domains that will be used for the two  websites. I'm going to try hosting on two difference accounts and hosting companies.